# DAG greyed out in the Spark UI once the job is over

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-ui

[image: Spark DAG]

One of my spark jobs takes is suffering from skewed partitions.

I made changes to the configurations `spark.sql.adaptive.skewJoin.skewedPartitionThresholdInBytes` and `spark.sql.adaptive.skewJoin.skewedPartitionFactor` and was trying to look at the details in Physical Query post execution of the job, to see if AQE was kicking in to mitigate the skew, however the DAG appears to be greyed out and none of the 'boxes' are expandable.

The details are available during the execution of the job, but appear to become greyed out once the application execution is complete.

Any pointers?